# How do I get the sum of each persons best ten scores of the season?

Tags: mysql, database

I have a database of results for a season of 25 games. However only each persons best ten scores count.
Can anybody tell me how to sum just the top ten scores of each person AND show the minimum score that was used in that sum (their tenth best).
The database has PlayerName, TournamentID, Points 
eg.

```
 - TounamentID  PlayerName  Points
 - 1             Jo           100
 - 1             Tel          50
 - 1             Kevin        75
 - 2             Jo           100
 - 2             Tel          50
 - 2             Kevin        75
 - 3             Jo           100
 - 3             Tel          50
 - 3             Kevin        75
 - 4             Jo           100
 - 4             Tel          50
 - 4             Kevin        75
 - 5             Jo           100
 - 5             Tel          50
 - 5             Kevin        75 etc
```

Many thanks in advance

EDIT *1*

At the moment I have this kind of working though it doesn't handle duplicate scores very well and can actual end up adding up the top 11 if there's a duplicate;

```
SELECT X.PlayerName, Sum(X.Points) AS SumOfPoints, Min(X.Points) AS Target
FROM SoP11PreBats AS X
WHERE (((10)>(SELECT count(*)
       FROM SoP11PreBats
      WHERE PlayerName = X.PlayerName
        AND Points > X.Points )))
GROUP BY X.PlayerName
ORDER BY Sum(X.Points) DESC;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a feeling this will not work:

```
SELECT *
FROM
  ( SELECT pd.PlayerName
         , ( SELECT SUM(t10.Points)
             FROM
               ( SELECT t10.Points
                 FROM SoP11PreBats AS t10
                 WHERE t10.PlayerName = pd.PlayerName
                 ORDER BY t10.Points DESC
                 LIMIT 10
               ) AS x
           ) AS Sum10
         , ( SELECT t10.Points
             FROM SoP11PreBats AS t10
             WHERE t10.PlayerName = pd.PlayerName
             ORDER BY t10.Points DESC
             LIMIT 1 OFFSET 9
           ) AS TenthBest
    FROM 
        ( SELECT DISTINCT PlayerName
          FROM SoP11PreBats
        ) AS pd
  ) AS y
ORDER BY Sum10 DESC
```

---

But this will:

```
SELECT pb.PlayerName  AS PlayerName  
     , COALESCE(SUM(p.Points),0) + pb.TenthBest*(10-COUNT(p.Points))
                      AS SumOfPoints
     , pb.TenthBest   AS Target
FROM
  ( SELECT pd.PlayerName
         , ( SELECT t10.Points
             FROM SoP11PreBats AS t10
             WHERE t10.PlayerName = pd.PlayerName
             ORDER BY t10.Points DESC
             LIMIT 1 OFFSET 9
           ) AS TenthBest
    FROM 
        ( SELECT DISTINCT PlayerName
          FROM SoP11PreBats
        ) AS pd
  ) AS pb
  LEFT JOIN SoP11PreBats AS p
    ON  p.PlayerName = pb.PlayerName
    AND p.Points > pb.TenthBest
GROUP BY pb.PlayerName
ORDER BY SumOfPoints DESC
```

Comment: No don't think so. It's the same as my last edit on the post above. The where t10.Playername = pd.Playername will not compile (pd not found)

Comment: @Eddy: Yes, I had a hunch it wouldn't work. Terry, try the update (sorry, I can't test now).

Comment: Hi - This Returns the following;
Radek 3193 9. Just one row and a huge total that far exceeds Radeks actual score.

Comment: @Terry: I forgot the `GROUP BY pb.PlayerName`

Comment: Perfect - Thanks. I guess I should use this one in case I ever deal with more data.

Comment: Welcome. If there is a chance that a player has less than 10 scores, change `AND p.Points > pb.TenthBest` to `AND (p.Points > pb.TenthBest OR pb.TenthBest IS NULL)` and `pb.TenthBest*(10-COUNT(p.Points))` to `COALESCE(pb.TenthBest,0)*(10-COUNT(p.Points))`. So, the sum of the (less than 10) scores is still shown.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this would work for one player at a time:

```
SELECT SUM(n), MIN(n) FROM
  (SELECT   points AS n
   FROM     table
   WHERE    PlayerName = ?
   ORDER BY n DESC
   LIMIT    10
  )
```

I'm not sure how to expand it to produce a table for *every* player.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT test.playername, sum(top10.score), MIN(top10.score)
FROM test
LEFT JOIN (SELECT playername, score FROM test ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 10) top10
ON top10.playername = test.playername
GROUP BY test.playername
```

Edit: Turns out the above approach using a subselect and join is not going to do the trick. Because you limit the results in the subselect it is not going to lead to a set of max 10 records PER playername. 
The next approach would be to do something like

```
SELECT pk, name, score from test where
pk IN (SELECT pk FROM test t2 WHERE t2.name = name ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 10)
```

This could create the proper set of records to join with. However LIMIT is not supported inside an IN clause (yet). So this won't compile.

EIDT2: The final approach I can think of goes like this:

```
select distinct test.name
, (SELECT sum(t2.score) FROM (select t3.score FROM test t3 WHERE t3.name = test.name ORDER BY score desc LIMIT 10) t2)
, (SELECT min(t2.score) FROM (select t3.score FROM test t3 WHERE t3.name = test.name ORDER BY score desc LIMIT 10) t2)
FROM test
```

This one also won't compile because the most inner test.name in the where can't be resolved properly.

I don't think that what you want to do can currently be done in 1 single query on mysql, but I'm curious if someone can proof me wrong.

Comment: Thanks for you quick responses guys. But I'm a bit of an amateur and can't get this to work. I have mysql on the webserver and access on my desktop and normally test in access and cut and paste the sql to the webserver. Some functions need replacing but it generally works. Will the above work on this setup? Also my table name is SoP11PreBATS. Do I just replace test with the actual table name?

Comment: Yes you can replace 'test' with 'SoP11PreBats'. It won't run on access but will on your webserver (the "LIMIT 10" is mysql specific). In SqlServer it would be "Select Top 10 player, ..." instead of the "Limit 10" part. Not 100% certain but that might also work on msaccess

Comment: (Select Top 10 playername, score from SoP11PreBats order by score DESC) should work on MsAccess (according to the 'limit results' paragraph in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Select_(SQL)

Comment: Thanks again. It's running but returning null fields or fields that far exceed the sum of the points. I'm trying to get my head around the top10.score part. Does this create a temp table called top10?

Comment: Sorry I missed you last post. Select Top 10 playername, score from SoP11PreBats order by score DESC just gives me the ten players with the highest single score. How do I stretch this to give me each players top 10 scores which I can then sum?

Comment: Thanks for you help but the part "SELECT playername, score FROM test ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 10" doesn't select each persons top ten scores but the top ten in the whole database. I'm back to the drawing board I'm afraid :-(

Comment: Yup this won't work and it needs to get a lot more complicated. Does your table have a primary key columns as well? We're gonna need it

Comment: At the moment SoP11PreBATS is a query of three tables that each have a primary key so I'm not sure of we can use that! I've got the following to work (SELECT X.PlayerName, Sum(X.Points) AS SumOfPoints, Min(X.Points) AS Target
FROM SoP11PreBats AS X
WHERE (((10)>(SELECT count(*)
       FROM SoP11PreBats
      WHERE PlayerName = X.PlayerName
        AND Points > X.Points )))
GROUP BY X.PlayerName
ORDER BY Sum(X.Points) DESC;) But it takes the top ten scores AND their duplicates and sums the lot.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I got it working but it's about the most nasty sql hack I could think of and I'm not sure you should even consider to put it in production like this. It also only runs on mysql:

```
select PlayerName, sum(Points), min(Points) from 
(select distinct SoP11PreBats.PlayerName, (SELECT t2.Points FROM test t2 WHERE t2.PlayerName = SoP11PreBats.PlayerName ORDER BY Points desc LIMIT 1) as Points FROM test 
UNION ALL
select distinct SoP11PreBats.PlayerName, (SELECT t2.Points FROM test t2 WHERE t2.PlayerName = SoP11PreBats.PlayerName ORDER BY Points desc LIMIT 1,1) as Points FROM test 
UNION ALL
select distinct SoP11PreBats.PlayerName, (SELECT t2.Points FROM test t2 WHERE t2.PlayerName = SoP11PreBats.PlayerName ORDER BY Points desc LIMIT 2,1) as Points FROM test 
UNION ALL
select distinct SoP11PreBats.PlayerName, (SELECT t2.Points FROM test t2 WHERE t2.PlayerName = SoP11PreBats.PlayerName ORDER BY Points desc LIMIT 3,1) as Points FROM test 
UNION ALL
select distinct SoP11PreBats.PlayerName, (SELECT t2.Points FROM test t2 WHERE t2.PlayerName = SoP11PreBats.PlayerName ORDER BY Points desc LIMIT 4,1) as Points FROM test 
UNION ALL
select distinct SoP11PreBats.PlayerName, (SELECT t2.Points FROM test t2 WHERE t2.PlayerName = SoP11PreBats.PlayerName ORDER BY Points desc LIMIT 5,1) as Points FROM test 
UNION ALL
select distinct SoP11PreBats.PlayerName, (SELECT t2.Points FROM test t2 WHERE t2.PlayerName = SoP11PreBats.PlayerName ORDER BY Points desc LIMIT 6,1) as Points FROM test 
UNION ALL
select distinct SoP11PreBats.PlayerName, (SELECT t2.Points FROM test t2 WHERE t2.PlayerName = SoP11PreBats.PlayerName ORDER BY Points desc LIMIT 7,1) as Points FROM test 
UNION ALL
select distinct SoP11PreBats.PlayerName, (SELECT t2.Points FROM test t2 WHERE t2.PlayerName = SoP11PreBats.PlayerName ORDER BY Points desc LIMIT 8,1) as Points FROM test 
UNION ALL
select distinct SoP11PreBats.PlayerName, (SELECT t2.Points FROM test t2 WHERE t2.PlayerName = SoP11PreBats.PlayerName ORDER BY Points desc LIMIT 9,1) as Points FROM test 
) top10
group by name
```

Comment: Mate this is brilliant and works BUT I can't save it as a view and this is a small part of a bigger query. I get the error; #1349 - View's SELECT contains a subquery in the FROM clause Is there a way to spit this into two separate queries?

Comment: Man you start to scare me. This is already over the top and this then becomes part of an even bigger query. You should really stop for a minute lean back and reconsider what you are doing and if this is the proper way to do it. Getting queries like that performing properly if the dataset grows will be hard or even impossible.

Comment: It's ok. I've spit this into two queries and it seems to work. Thanks very much for all the time you've spent on this.

Comment: Sorry missed your last post. There will only ever be points in the database for about 100 players and 25 games. It seems to run ok at the moment and is very fast. But we only have the results of 15 games so far. Do you foresee a problem if it gets to 25?

Comment: Wouldn't expect much difference going from 15 to 25. Might wanna mark this question as answered then.

Answer (score 0):

This works (see test output below):

```
set @count:=0, @player:='';
SELECT 
    PlayerName,
    SUM(Points) as sum_top_10, 
    MIN(Points) as min_top_10
FROM (SELECT PlayerName, Points
    FROM (SELECT
    Points, 
        @count := if (@player != PlayerName, 0, @count + 1) as count, 
        @player := PlayerName as PlayerName
        FROM (SELECT PlayerName, Points FROM SoP11PreBATS order by 1, 2 desc) x) y
    where count < 10) z
group by 1;
```

Here's the test, using OP's data, plus extra rows for 'Jo' to make more than 10 rows:

```
create table SoP11PreBATS (TounamentID int, PlayerName text,  Points int);
delete from SoP11PreBATS;
insert into SoP11PreBATS values
(1, 'Jo', 100), (1, 'Tel', 50), (1, 'Kevin', 75), (2, 'Jo', 100), (2, 'Tel', 50),
(2, 'Kevin', 75), (3, 'Jo', 100), (3, 'Tel', 50), (3, 'Kevin', 75), (4, 'Jo', 100),
(4, 'Tel', 50), (4, 'Kevin', 75), (5, 'Jo', 100), (5, 'Tel', 50), (5, 'Kevin', 75),
(5, 'Jo', 50), (6, 'Jo', 75), (7, 'Jo', 100), (8, 'Jo', 50), (9, 'Jo', 75),
(10, 'Jo', 50), (11, 'Jo', 75), (12, 'Jo', 100);
select * from SoP11PreBATS where playername = 'Jo' order by points desc;
+-------------+------------+--------+
| TounamentID | PlayerName | Points |
+-------------+------------+--------+
|           1 | Jo         |    100 |
|           2 | Jo         |    100 |
|           3 | Jo         |    100 |
|           4 | Jo         |    100 |
|           5 | Jo         |    100 |
|           7 | Jo         |    100 |
|          12 | Jo         |    100 |
|           6 | Jo         |     75 |
|           9 | Jo         |     75 |
|          11 | Jo         |     75 |
|           5 | Jo         |     50 |
|           8 | Jo         |     50 |
|          10 | Jo         |     50 |
+-------------+------------+--------+
-- Inspection shows Jo should have 925 as sum and 75 as min
-- Ran query above and got:
+------------+------------+------------+
| PlayerName | sum_top_10 | min_top_10 |
+------------+------------+------------+
| Jo         |        925 |         75 |
| Kevin      |        375 |         75 |
| Tel        |        250 |         50 |
+------------+------------+------------+
-- Test output correct
```

Comment: Hi I tried this on my server bt got the following error; #1267 - Illegal mix of collations (utf8_unicode_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_general_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation '<>' Do you know what that means?

Comment: Seems your encoding is incompatible with this syntax.

Comment: @Terry: Probably the `@player != PlayerName` is causing this. I'm not sure how collations are used with variables though (so no advice on how to get around this error)

Answer (score 0):

I think this works, and it only uses one derived table:

```
  SELECT @row := 0, @pp := NULL, @min := 0;
  SELECT Player,
         SUM(Points) AS Points,
         MIN(Points) AS MinPoints
    FROM (
  SELECT Player,
         Points,
         @row := IF(
           IFNULL(@pp, '') <> Player AND NOT (@pp := Player),
           1,
           @row + 1
         ) AS Row
    FROM SoP11PreBats
ORDER BY Player, Points DESC
) tmp
   WHERE tmp.Row <= 10
GROUP BY Player;
```

Test data:

```
CREATE TABLE `SoP11PreBats` (
 `TournamentID` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `Player` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `Points` int(11) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO SoP11PreBats (TournamentID, Player, Points) VALUES
(15, 'Jo',     10),
(14, 'Jo',     20),
(13, 'Jo',     30),
(12, 'Jo',     40),
(11, 'Jo',     50),
(10, 'Jo',     60),
( 9, 'Jo',     70),
( 8, 'Jo',     80),
( 7, 'Jo',     90),
( 6, 'Jo',    100),
( 5, 'Jo',    110),
( 4, 'Jo',    120),
( 3, 'Jo',    130),
( 2, 'Jo',    140),
( 1, 'Jo',    150),
( 1, 'Tel',    15),
( 2, 'Tel',    25),
( 3, 'Tel',    35),
( 4, 'Tel',    45),
( 5, 'Tel',    55),
( 6, 'Tel',    65),
( 7, 'Tel',    75),
( 8, 'Tel',    85),
( 9, 'Tel',    95),
(10, 'Tel',   105),
(11, 'Tel',   115),
(12, 'Tel',   125),
(13, 'Tel',   135),
(14, 'Tel',   145),
(15, 'Tel',   155),
( 1, 'Kevin',  10),
( 2, 'Kevin',  20),
( 3, 'Kevin',  30),
( 4, 'Kevin',  40),
( 5, 'Kevin',  50),
( 6, 'Kevin',  60),
( 7, 'Kevin',  70),
( 8, 'Kevin',  80),
( 9, 'Kevin',  90),
(10, 'Kevin', 100),
(11, 'Kevin', 110),
(12, 'Kevin', 120),
(13, 'Kevin', 130),
(14, 'Kevin', 140),
(15, 'Kevin', 150);
```

Result:

```
+--------+--------+-----------+
| Player | Points | MinPoints |
+--------+--------+-----------+
| Jo     |   1050 |        60 |
| Kevin  |   1050 |        60 |
| Tel    |   1100 |        65 |
+--------+--------+-----------+
```